# Parse.com Login screen i18n with iOS

Tags: ios, parse-platform

I'm trying to internationalize the Parse.com Login screen at an iOS 8 app without success. I'm following the [parse docs](https://parse.com/docs/ios/guide#user-interface-customizing-localizing-string-resources), but nothing happens. I'm providing a [sample project](https://github.com/felipelc/ios8-i18n-sample) with a signup page. Take a look at Localizable.strings files to see that the localized text was provided:

```
/* 
  Localizable.strings
  ParseI18nSample
*/
"The email address is invalid. Please enter a valid email." = "EN invalid email";
"Please enter a username." = "EN username blank";
"Please enter a password." = "EN password blank";
"Please enter an email." = "EN email blank";
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Rename your "Localizable.strings" file to "ParseUI.strings". The Parse UI will use the i18n from this file.